# exception handling

Tags: c++, exception

Sorry, I did not provide the code when I posted earlier, due to the indentation. Now, I am providing the code. As I mentioned earlier, I threw an exception inside the sample code, and i still have a 0 which is returned by the code. I have spent some times trying to figure out, but I could not come with the exact answer.

```
#include <stdexcept> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 


class myException_Product_Not_Found: public exception  
{ 
    public: 
      virtual const char* what() const throw() 
     { 
      return "Product not found"; 
     } 

} myExcept_Prod_Not_Found;   

int getProductID(int ids[], string names[], int numProducts, string target) 
{ 

   for(int i=0; i<numProducts; i++)  
   { 
      if(names[i]==target) 
        return ids[i];           
   }  
    try 
    { 
     throw myExcept_Prod_Not_Found;    
    } 
     catch (exception& e) 
    { 
     cout<<e.what()<<endl;      
    }                                        
} 

int main() //sample code to test the getProductID function 
{ 
  int productIds[]={4,5,8,10,13}; 
  string products[]={"computer","flash drive","mouse","printer","camera"}; 
  cout<<getProductID(productIds, products, 5, "computer")<<endl; 
  cout<<getProductID(productIds, products, 5, "laptop")<<endl; 
  cout<<getProductID(productIds, products, 5, "printer")<<endl;   
  return 0; 
}
```

c++ exception

Comment: possible duplicate of [The sample code provided returns a random number, even after throwing an exception (code provided)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420793/the-sample-code-provided-returns-a-random-number-even-after-throwing-an-exceptio)

Comment: Dude, wtf. You already asked this.

Answer (score 2):

```
try 
{ 
 throw myExcept_Prod_Not_Found;    
} 
 catch (exception& e) 
{ 
 cout<<e.what()<<endl;      
}
```

You are catching the exception, essentially saying that you are handling it with the message printed to cout.

This will re-throw the exception if you wish to propagate it.

```
try 
{ 
 throw myExcept_Prod_Not_Found;    
} 
 catch (exception& e) 
{ 
 cout<<e.what()<<endl;      
 throw;
}
```

If you wanted to not return 0 from your main function after you've propagated, you have to do that yourself.

```
int main()
{ 
  try {
    // ...
  } catch (...) {
    return 1;
  }   
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom, after adding "throw" I obtained what I wanted but, I also got an error message. Here is the message that I got: "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the aplication's support team for more information."

Comment: @T3000 That is the expected behavior.  Windows just tells you (the user of the application) that the programmer (also happens to be you) messed up somehow.  I don't know how you want to handle it, but I'll guess and update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getProductID()` function doesn't return from all possible execution paths. So when the function exits without a `return` statement, you get random garbage. This is the case when the product string isn't found.

Your `try`/`catch` block is a red herring, as it doesn't affect the remainder of the code in any way (the exception is caught immediately).

Two unrelated tips for improvement:

1. Catch exceptions by constant reference.
2. Use `std::find` rather than your manual loop; that way, you can write the entire function body in two lines.
3. Don't use C-style arrays; instead, use `std::vector`.

Comment: I even tried using a boolean such that if the target has been found, the the value of the boolean is true, otherwise it is false. Then, I check the value of the boolean, if it is false (once we left the loop for) then try/catch. But it did not take me anywhere.

Comment: @T3000 -- what has that to do with anything?